# How to resolve error in async pipe applied for searching in table?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

Here i am tryining to apply searchinh in table with ng-bootstrap in angular , there error in async pipe "InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'". I have done accuratly same on ng-bootstrap site.

this is my Html table, here I have applied to filter.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  
          <thead class="thead-dark">
  
            <tr>
              <th>S.No.</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th>Date Of Birth</th>
              <th>Contact Number</th>
              <th>Image</th>
              <th>Action</th>
              
            </tr>
          </thead>
  
          <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="  let recentDetails of user$ | async; index as i ">
              <td >{{i+1+((tableModel.Page-1)*tableModel.pageSize)}}</td>
              <td ><ngb-highlight [result]="recentDetails.name" [term]="filter.value"></ngb-highlight></td>
              <td ><ngb-highlight [result]="recentDetails.email" [term]="filter.value"></ngb-highlight></td>
              <td ><ngb-highlight [result]="recentDetails.dateOfBirth" [term]="filter.value"></ngb-highlight></td>
              <td ><ngb-highlight [result]="recentDetails.contactNumber" [term]="filter.value"></ngb-highlight></td>
              <td><img src="https://localhost:44342/Images/{{recentDetails.userImageGuid}}"></td> 
              <td> <button class="btn btn-warning" (click)="editUserDetails(recentDetails.email)">Edit</button> &nbsp;
                <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteRow(recentDetails.id,i)">Delete</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
```

Now this is a function for searching

```
function search(text: string): User[] {
  return this.user$.filter(user => {
    const term = text.toLowerCase();
    return user.name.toLowerCase().includes(term)
  });
}
```

can you please help me out why async getting [object, object]
the same thing is done on the ng-bootstrap website but there is no error

Thank you in advance.

Comment: did u try with custom pipe ?

Comment: @pc_coder No, Actually on ng-bootstrap it is done with async pipe. So, that means there is no need for custom pipe

Comment: I mean pipe for filter ?

Comment: @pc_coder What is the requirement for that pipe?

Comment: can you please help me out?